# How to calculate and insert values into a table, but the calculation depends on data from different tables?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

EXAMPLE: I have three tables car, payment, rental

```
CREATE TABLE car(
    car_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    price_per_day REAL NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE payment(
    payment_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    rental_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    payment_amount REAL NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE rental(
    rental_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    rental_time VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, --timestamp values    
    car_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
);
```

I want to calculate the **payment_amount**, but have to take exactly that data from a different table, have to take the **rental_time**(days) from the *rental* table and multiply by **price_per_day** from another table(*car*), but have to take exactly that price (it's about **car_id**) and insert into the *payment* table in the **payment_amount** column.

I tried

```
UPDATE payment
    SET p.payment_amount = (SELECT r.rental_time WHERE r.car_id=1)*(SELECT c.price_per_day WHERE c.car_id=1)
        FROM payment p, rental r, car c;
```

ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying * real

LINE 2: ...((SELECT r.rental_time WHERE r.car_id=1)*(SELECT c...

[See what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jlrz.png)

why are the column data the same if It should change depending on car_id and different price (price_per_day)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]I would just join the 3 tables.

```
UPDATE payment
  SET 
      payment_amount =
(
    SELECT(r.rental_time * c.price_per_day) AS payment_amount
    FROM car c
         JOIN rental r ON c.car_id = r.car_id
         JOIN payment p ON p.rental_id = r.rental_id
    WHERE c.car_id = 1
);
```

Comment: Another problem ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying * real, but then i try to change type to INTEGER  "ERROR:  column "rental_time" cannot be cast automatically to type integer"

Comment: Okey, SOLVED :D

Comment: Oh good, happy to hear. Have a good one!                                                                 
Interesting. I created those tables exactly as you had them, before I tested out my sql and I got 0 errors. Either way, glad it worked out for you.